# Is there spatial data loss in light passing through transparent crystal?

Tags: optics, visible-light, photons, interference, diffraction

There is perfect parallelepipedal bar made of transparent crystal with cubic lattice floating in vacuum. Faces of parallelepiped are parallel to lattice axis. There is image, forming checkerboard pattern, each cell alternating between two distinct colors.

This image is projected in perpendicular on the one face of crystal bar, so projection has spatial resolution (e.g. density of outgoing photons) such high, so every single molecule in the first layer of crystal bar gets several photons of different wavelength.

Questions:

1. How the output image at the opposite side of crystal bar compares to original image projected?
2. Will it correlate to thickness of bar?
3. How are multiple photons hitting same molecule handled?
4. What is the limit of resolution of incoming image, to perfectly match output image? Is it one-to-one correspondence of incoming photons to molecules in the first layer?
5. Will there be scattering of photons on the molecules of the last layer? If any, will interference between scattered photons cancel non-perpendicular directions?